# The debugger is not attached - Xdebug - Atom (php)

Tags: php, debugging, wamp, xdebug

I'm attempting to install xdebug on to my atom in order to debug my magento 2 code on a wamp server. I think i have installed xdebug successfully according to my phpinfo() file however when I come to attach a debugger in atom, xdebug doesn't appear.

My php.ini settings are:

```
 ; XDEBUG Extension
 [xdebug]
 zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.16/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.1- 
 vc14-x86_64.dll"
 xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.remote_autostart=true
 ;xdebug.profiler_enable = off
 ;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
 ;xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
 ;xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
 ;xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

I haven't managed to find a complete tutorial online that works. I was following the [Atom Tutorial](https://atom.io/packages/php-debug), however I could not get it to work. I think the error may be with the IDE key as i'm not sure what to do with it. I've followed almost every youtube video but it still seems i'm doing something wrong. 
If someone could post a working tutorial I would very much appreciate it. Thanks in advance :)

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8LA0.png)

PHP Version 7.1.16
Xdebug Version 2.6.1

Comment: WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG **already installed** look at the bottom of the `php.ini` file. If you want to amend the parameters do it there

Comment: What am I changing so that it will work with Atom? Also, should it just appear in the attach debugger page?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Atom, is that an IDE?

Comment: Yeah, click the link and see if you can make sense of it. I don't even get the green line when i add a break point.

Comment: Oh and by the way there is a newer version of `XDEBUG V2.6.1` which you say you are using, but your `zend_extension` is using `XDEBUG V2.6.0` there is an ADDON Upgrade on the WAMPServer [backup repo here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Comment: Well it works out of the box (with a few param changes) on NetBeans and Eclipse

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with both atom and xdebug which doesn't help. The tutorials were not very helpful

Comment: Thinking about it, I changed params to ........

Comment: `xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400;
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 9000
xdebug.remote_log="d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0`

Comment: Haven't managed to fix it, I switched to Visual Studio code and it was already setup

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in the comment section of the question, that you have moved to Visual Studio Code, But I'll write down this answer anyway as someone else may find it helpful.

I've also came across this issue: "Debugger not attached".

When you install `php-debug` it **require** one more package: `atom-debug-ui` - which is not the issue.

Once `php-debug` is installed it also **recommends** to install couple more packages: `ide-php` and `atom-ide-ui`. The latter package can be problematic as it also contains it's own debugger UI.

Therefore when you install all four packages, there are two set of debugger UIs running on your Atom IDE.

To overcome this, what you should do is [disabling `atom-ide-ui`'s debugger](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug/issues/310#issuecomment-419751273).  You can also go ahead and uninstall `atom-ide-ui` as it's not required for `php-debug` to run. If `ide-php` package depends on `atom-ide-ui`, you can uninstall `ide-php` as well.

I understand the question is about a setup which runs on WAMP. I've written [this article](https://medium.com/@parakramapp/getting-xdebug-to-work-with-atom-text-editor-for-php-8-project-884194e206b1) on how to set it up on Ubuntu based Linux. In that article I've provided all the details you want. I don't think it would be too hard to translate the information to Windows based setup.

Comment: After install xdebug  ide is showing this msg : "The debugger is not attached ". In php --version xdebug is showing with version